# Draw a MKPolyline on a MapView shows straight line between both locations

Tags: ios, iphone, mkannotation, apple-maps, mkpolyline

How to get location like google maps which shows exact paths between locations. As it shows direct straight line which does not contain any path between both places and neither shows location around them through which it passes.
I have used following code:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[2];
    coordinateArray[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5074, 0.1278);
    coordinateArray[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48.8566, 2.3522);


    self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];
    [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]]; //If you want the route to be visible

    [self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
```

For connection of both the paths this code have been implemented.

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if(overlay == self.routeLine)
    {
        if(nil == self.routeLineView)
        {
            self.routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];
            self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 5;

        }

        return self.routeLineView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my code one:

```
- (void)drawRouteFromLocation:(LocationPin *)source toLocation:(LocationPin *)destination

{
    [self removeCurrentRouteDrawing];

    MKPlacemark *sourcePlaceMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:source.actualCoordinate addressDictionary:nil];
    MKPlacemark *destinationPlaceMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:destination.actualCoordinate addressDictionary:nil];

    MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];

    request.source = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:sourcePlaceMark];
    request.destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:destinationPlaceMark];
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = NO;
    MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         if (error)
         {
             // Handle Error
         }
         else
         {
             [self showRoute:response];
         }
     }];
}

-(void)showRoute:(MKDirectionsResponse *)response
{
    for (MKRoute *route in response.routes)
    {
        [self.mkMapView addOverlay:route.polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
//        for (MKRouteStep *step in route.steps)
//        {
//            DEBUG_LOG(@"%@", step.instructions);
//        }

    }
}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
//    DEBUG_LOG(@"region Will Change");

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:)])
    {
        [self.delegate mapView:mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:animated];
    }

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
//    DEBUG_LOG(@"region Did Change");

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:)])
    {
        [self.delegate mapView:mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:animated];
    }

}

- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView
{
    DEBUG_LOG(@"mapView Did Finish Loading Map");
    self.mapInitialized = YES;

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:)])
    {
        [self.delegate mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:mapView];
    }
}

//- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
//{
//    if ([overlay isKindOfClass: [MKPolyline class]])
//    {
//        // This is for a dummy overlay to work around a problem with overlays
//        // not getting removed by the map view even though we asked for it to
//        // be removed.
//        MKOverlayView * dummyView = [[MKOverlayView alloc] init];
//        dummyView.alpha = 0.0;
//        return dummyView;
//    }
//    else
//    {
//        return nil;
//    }
//}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(mapView:viewForAnnotation:)])
    {
        return [self.delegate mapView:mapView viewForAnnotation:annotation];
    }

    return nil;
}

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[ MKPolylineRenderer alloc]initWithOverlay:overlay];
        renderer.lineWidth = 10;
        renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
        [self _zoomToPolyLine:self.mkMapView polyLine:overlay animated:YES];
        return renderer;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}


#pragma mark - Utils

-(void)_zoomToPolyLine:(MKMapView*)map polyLine:(MKPolyline*)polyLine animated:(BOOL)animated
{
//    MKPolygon* polygon =
//    [MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:polyLine.points count:polyLine.pointCount];
//    
//    [self.mkMapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect([polygon boundingMapRect])
//          animated:animated];

    [map setVisibleMapRect:[polyLine boundingMapRect] edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(35.0, 35.0, 35.0, 35.0) animated:animated];
}

- (void)removeCurrentRouteDrawing
{
    if (self.mkMapView.overlays.count)
    {
        [self.mkMapView removeOverlays:self.mkMapView.overlays];

    }
}
```